# Set up global variables and database in an object oriented php

Tags: php, oop, constants, global

Here's my problem:

```
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) die;
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

if ( !class_exists( 'MyPlugin' ) ) {

    class MyPlugin {

        protected $MyPluginTable;
        protected $wpdb;
        protected $MyPluginPerfix = 'MyPlugin_';

        public function __construct() {

            define( $MyPluginPerfix' . _ROOTDIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );

            register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($this ,'MyPluginInstall') );
            register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($this ,'MyPluginDeactivation') );

            global $wpdb;
            $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
            $this->MyPluginTable = $this->wpdb->prefix . "MyPluginTable";

        }
}
```

As you can notice, I'm trying to set up some constant, that I can reuse everywhere in my code (a WordPress plugin).

The first problem is that the defined constant won't work.

The second problem is the way to define a global variable in PHP, I'm fine with the way I call my database:

```
$this->NetrackTable
```

But the way I defined the table in my database (as a global) was too verbose.

I was wondering if there is a better way to use and define those entities in PHP, in order to write more elegant code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the variable in the __construct method of your Class.

Comment: Which one or how? I don't think that the dynamic one will work

Comment: @user3833012 replace database method with __construct, and define your variable in top of your class scope.

Comment: I tried, please could you provide an example? Mine didn't work:

error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results()

Comment: class TestPlugin {
 protected $usersTable;

 public function __construct() {
  global $wpdb;
  $this->usersTable = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
 }

 public function get_users() {
  global $wpdb;

  return $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$this->usersTable}" );
 }
}